# Can I share entities between solutions?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a problem with sharing entities in 2 different solutions. 
I have one entity (`Country`) that I need in 2 solutions. One solution it's a web application and the other it's a console application but I need this entity in both.

Additionally, we are doing migrations and I don't know what the behaviour of code first is in this case if I change the entity twice one per solution.

It is possible to share entities between solutions in entity framework 6 code first?

Comment: What do you mean by sharing?

Comment: Yes, put your entities in a class library and reference that in both your web and console applications. In fact, I would recommend doing that as best practice.

Comment: @DavidG Thanks for your answer, I was trying to avoid spliting the code, I liked to do it separated in first place, but it was not possible. If there is no other solution I'll split it, but I would like explore other options first (if it exist)

Comment: @MarcRomero In my experience, saving time now will cost you lots more in the future. Do the right thing today and save heartache in the future :)

Comment: Thanks @DavidG, finally I'll split my infrastruture in other project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to use an entitie which is contained in a project and use it botjh in a web project and a console project. You can do that by referencing the output dll of your entities project from where you need it.

In your case you would add a reference to entities.dll on the consoleapplication project and another one on the webapplication project.

Personally I would have all the projects in the same solution and reference each project I needed. But it is possible to do it your way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Ninglin but I have my Infraestructure in a project that I cannot share because contains more modules separated in folders with other functionalities. I want to duplicate my entity, but I don't know if I can.

if I cannot, then I'll create a project just for my database as you said.

Thanks again for your answer!

Comment: Oh okay. To my knowledge (which is not very extensive), the only solution I see is replicating your entity on the project you want to use it. The downside is that whenever you change your model you will have to reflect the changes on both sides. Or you could implement an interface to serve as a contract for your entity so that you can manage changes more easily. I don't know if that breaks your code first migrations, but I believe that It will not.